# Java Web Start application not updating

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have been battling for days to get my java app to work with Java Web Start, specifically the auto update feature. I have got my app loading just fine, but when I update the files, the app is still running through the cache and not downloading the newer version.
I have been using Netbeans to do most of the JNLP file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="Cray Lobster DataBase V1.02.jnlp">
  <update check="always" policy="always"/> 
  <information>
    <title>Cray Lobster DataBase V1.02</title>
    <vendor>Zebra Tech</vendor>
    <description></description>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="CrayFishDataBase.jar" />
    <jar href="lib/guava-14.0.1.jar" />
    <jar href="lib/javolution-5.3.1-javadoc.jar" />
    <jar href="lib/javolution-core-java-6.0.0-20120916.141438-2.jar" />
    <jar href="lib/jfxmessagebox-1.1.0.jar" />
    <jar href="lib/jfxtras-labs-2.2-r4-javadoc.jar" />
    <jar href="lib/jfxtras-labs-2.2-r4.jar" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
  <update check="always"/>
</jnlp>
```

Why does the application not auto-update?

Comment: The update tag is twice in there. Although I don't think that's the cause ...

Comment: I just notice that too, I have change it and it the behaviour has not change.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).